# Linux "Sudo -l" Privilege escalation issue

Tags: sudo, kali-linux, privileges

Hi all I'm moderately new to Linux so hoping I can get some help.. I am currently running Kali Linux and trying to practice privilege escalation using `sudo -l`. As background, I currently am accessing a system as `user1` but do not have access to their password. When running `sudo -l` i'm getting the following results:

```
sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for user1 on thisdevice:
    env_reset, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin

User user1 may run the following commands on thisdevice:
    (user2) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/vi /home/user2/details.txt
```

to my knowledge, it means that I as `user1` should be able to use `sudo vi` command to access the `details.txt` file in the `user2` directory? however when attempting to perform `sudo vi`, I am still being asked to provide password for `user1`.

Does anyone know by any chance if I am making a mistake or potentially some help? I have been on [GTFOBINS](https://gtfobins.github.io) (a curated list of Unix binaries that can be exploited by an attacker to bypass local security restrictions) looking at `vi` but can't seem to progress after this part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sudo` command provides intentional privilege escalation - that's exactly why it exists.

The `sudoers` definition you have shown is very specific: it allows you to use `/usr/bin/vi` to edit the precise file path `/home/user2/details.txt`. This command would work

```
sudo -u user2 vi /home/user2/details.txt
```

But this one would not

```
cd /home/user2
sudo -u user2 vi details.txt
```

I've seen that you mention `sudo vi`. You do not have permissions to do that, as the implied target user for `sudo` is `root` unless otherwise specified with the `-u` option.

Note that there is a trivial break from `sudo [options] vi ...` in that `vi`'s  `:shell` command will execute an interactive shell as the target user.